# Add unique id to merged attributes tables QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, plugins, function

I need to find a way to stack up numeric id fields from two tables without duplications.
To put it simply here is what I want to do schematically :

**Table 1**

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

**Table 2**

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

**Expected result** (Addition and reset of table 2 Id)

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I'm currently copy/pasting and editing rows manually but it's completely suboptimal and time consuming.
Any ideas, plugins, functions...?

Answer (score 2):

Using the DB manager SQL window on some mock-up layers:

Table 1:

[image]

And table 2:

[image]

I can write a SQL to union them together with all records together but a useless ID column that contains duplicates, but both tables:

[image]

But by using a sub-query and the row_number function, I can create a new unique ID column simply numbering the records:

[image]

From there you can load the result into the QGIS window and export it to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Using DPSSpatial SQL function I tried to subquery two tables which where **NOT ascending ordered** with DB Manager virtual layers as following :

```
WITH query_name1 AS (
     SELECT * FROM layer1 ORDER BY field ASC
     )
   , query_name2 AS (
     SELECT * FROM layer2 ORDER BY field ASC
     )
SELECT
row_number() over () AS newunique_id
, data.* from

(
SELECT * FROM query_name1
union
SELECT * FROM query_name2
)
AS data
```

However It did'nt worked as expected as layers 1 and 2 did'nt came up ordered by ascending. Any tips to make it work ?